# Error while publishing from Tridion 5.3

Tags: tridion

We have recently set up new tridion content manager server as well as content delivery server (Tridion 5.3). We are using .net in content delivery.

When we try to publish from content manager we are getting below mentioned error.

Access is denied for the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM: directory services are not enabled.

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue.

We have changed Publishing Target as per new url.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get the error - there are many stages to Publishing.

Comment: That sounds like a misconfiguration on your MMC snap-in ("directory services"). It would seem like something is wrong with the configuration and I would start comparing with a working system (if you have one)

Comment: We are using Trdion 5.3, in publishing queue trasaction is failed, so double click and check it it shows above error.  Yes we do have a working system, should I check configuration on CMS machine ? or on Content delivery machine ?

Comment: On the Content Manager machine.

Comment: Hi Nuno,  I checked the Directory services on Content Manager server.  They are set for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM even the Active Directory setting are also there.  As suggested by you I also compared the configuration with working machine it is same except, the user icon (shown before caption) for "Directory services" and "Active Directory" are disabled/inactive.  On working machine they are shown as Enabled/Active.

Comment: Usually NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM is configured as Tridion user. Have you checked that this user is added as user in Tridion?

Comment: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM is not a added in Tridion, should I add it.  Actually I did not get it why this has to be added in Tridion, is it related impersonate user ?

Comment: when right click on "Directory Services" in popup I can see "tick mark" on "Directory Services Enabled" still I am facing the same issue.  But as mentioned earlier look and feel of user Icon shown on Directory services and Active directly is like disabled one.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a guess. Have you configured  SYSTEM as a directory service impersonation user?

Comment: In Directory Services under "Set system account name" I have configured "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"

Comment: That's something else. Check in your impersonation users. That's a different item in the management snap-in